# HttpHandler on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, httphandler

I am working on Win7 x64 using VS 2012 on a webapp.
I have some httphandlers that work fine on localhost (during debug from VS on IIS express).
The handlers are specified on Web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="login.ashx" type="MyWebApp.Logic.LoginHandler" />
   </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

When i publish the webapp to Azure (mydomain.azurewebsites.net/login.ashx) the handlers do not work on.

I found that i had to remove the httphandler from

```
<system.web> <httpHandlers>
```

and add it to

```
<system.webServer> <handlers>
```

But now it stopped working on the local host even if i keep in **system.web** and **system.webServer**.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: Have you tried having the verbs in both handlers and httpHandlers?

Comment: In you cloud service project's properties how are you running the web server?  IIS or IIS express?

Answer (score 2):

Your localhost is using Classic mode, while Azure uses Integrated mode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Just change your local IIS to use Integrated mode and everything will work the same.