# How to deploy proxy.ashx in Azure app Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ashx, azure-appservice

I'm looking for someone who has deployed proxy.ashx in Azure app service and made it work as on Windows VM it works fine but when I deployed on App service it doesn't work

Comment: have you included the <httpHandlers> in the web.config ?

Comment: I added the httphandler in web.config but it is giving 500.13 generic error,do you have a example project which you have dpeloyed on App service which has httphandler proxy deployed?

Comment: not really ... I don't even know if it's possible. I would recommend you containerize your app and try to run from it

Answer (score 0):

> How to deploy proxy.ashx in Azure app Service

- As mentioned by Thiago Custodio in the comment, we need to include `httphandlers` in the `web.config` file for `httphandlers` to work in Azure Web App.
- As per this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27186981), Azure uses the Integrated mode ,so we need to register `HTTP Handlers`  in **Integrated Mode**

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <handlers>
>       <!-- Register the HttpHandler used for My Handler requests (IIS 7.0+ running in Integrated Mode)  -->
>       <add name="SampleHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" 
>         verb="GET" path="SampleHandler.ashx"
>         type="YourWebApp.Web.SampleHandler"/>
>     </handlers>  
>    </system.webServer>
> ```

- Add the `httphandlers` to bin folder of Azure Web App Service, this can be done by adding the extensions in Azure Portal- KUDU Console -   `https://DeployedAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net`

> 500.13 generic error

Please follow the steps provided here  for [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#slow-or-hanging-app-azure-app-service) 500 series errors

***References taken from***

[ASP.NET HTTP Handlers on Azure](https://bytenota.com/asp-net-http-handlers-not-working-on-azure/)